# How to translate "Any()" and "All()" to DB2 SQL query?

Tags: c#, sql, database, db2

I am a newbie in DB2 world and am using:
- DB2 Data Provider for .NET (IBM.Data.DB2.dll version 9.7.4.4)
- C# VS2010 with .NET Framework 4.0

1. I am trying to translate following C# query statement:

> ```
> TestQuery(() => db.Customers.Any());
> ```

to (DB2) SQL query:

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN (EXISTS(
  SELECT NULL 
  FROM "CUSTOMERS" t0
  )) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "value"
```

The query above works on **MS SQL troublefree**. But **DB2 doesn't accept that query** and raises ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/NT64] SQL0104N

1. I get also same issue for "All()"

> ```
> TestQuery(() => db.Customers.All(c => c.ContactName.StartsWith("a")));
> ```

(DB2) SQL query:

```
  SELECT CASE WHEN (NOT (EXISTS(
  SELECT NULL 
  FROM "CUSTOMERS" t0
  WHERE NOT ((t0."CONTACTNAME" LIKE :p0 || '%'))
  ))) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "value"
```

**My question: How to translate "Any()" and "All()" to DB2 SQL query correctly?**
Any help and hints are highly appreciated. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DB2 `SELECT` must be `FROM` something. You could use the system table `SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1` that always has 1 row:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (EXISTS(
 SELECT NULL 
 FROM "CUSTOMERS" t0
)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "value"
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

or use the `VALUES` statement:

```
VALUES
CASE WHEN (EXISTS(
 SELECT NULL 
 FROM "CUSTOMERS" t0
)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS "value"
```